# Secret in compose file docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I want to encrypt my password in compose file,so I think that secrets is the solition , but when I implement it in my compose file: 
`$ docker stack deploy --compose-file=docker-compose-stack-dev.yml` secret

> secrets Additional property secrets is not allowed

When I use version 3, then When I moditfy it to 3.1 I have this error:

> my_secret_data Additional property my_secret_data is not allowed

Comment: As i know secrets are file-based. So you have to put your password in a file and include it in your `docker-compose.yml`. The `stack deploy` command adds the file as a Docker secret. Can you show us your `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: I create a secret with :  $ echo "This is a secret" | docker secret create my_secret_data - ,

Comment: then I add my compose file by adding                                                        secrets:                    # secrets block only for 'web' service
            - my_secret_data and  secrets:                        # top level secrets block
        my_secret_data:
            external: true

Comment: Isn't `secrets` a Docker Swarm feature only?

Comment: [Docker secrets are only available to swarm services, not to standalone containers.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)

Comment: @AlexKarshin Thats true, secrets are not possible in standalone containers, but `docker-compose` can *fake* them. 
Neverless `docker stack deploy` deploys services on a swarm.

Comment: @Ammy19 If you already created your secret and defined it as external in the docker-compose.yml file you should good to go. Maybe there is an indentation problem or an old docker version?

Comment: @manixx docker -v
Docker version 17.06.0-ce